# Angular is not processing part of a view; No error in console

Tags: angularjs

I have an odd issue where everything on the page is being processed by angular except for one small part helping to assign a CSS property.

```
.full-page(ng-repeat="page in pageRange(section.id)" style="top:{{(pageHeight * $index) + (15 * $index)}}px;")
```

in IE I am seeing

```
top: {{((pageHeight * $index) + (15 * $index))}}px
```

and in Chrome I am getting

```
top: 0px
```

pageHeight appears to be coming from its controller via

```
$scope.pageHeight
```

I'm pretty new to angular and working on a project that uses it on the front end. I having a hard time figuring out why IE not calculating. From what I can tell Chrome isn't either its just defaulting to 0px. I've been researching online and playing around with different ways to write it but I can seem to get anything to trigger is expected.

Comment: [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Thank you so much! It took some googling but yes ngstyle did what I needed!